# How to plot multiple models val and traing acc/loss curve from csv files?

Tags: computer-vision, matplotlib

I trained multiple CNN models, after that, I saved models details (Like , training/Validation Acc/Loss )  by callbacks by using this codes :

```
tf.keras.callbacks.CSVLogger
```

Now I have multiple models training-val acc-loss respective values in different **csv files**. 
**I want to plots those in one figure from my csv files. How can I do this**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps I solve my problem:

- Save Statistical records (Training-Validation Accuraciers, Training-Validation Recall, Training-Validation Precisions, Training-Validation F1) from CSV files of this following code `tf.keras.callbacks.CSVLogger` after training each fold (I trained for the 3 Folds).
- And load those csv files in the list:
      `import pandas as pd`
      `l = ["/Records_of_Fold_2.csv" , "/Records_of_Fold_3.csv"]`
- After that, Plot using matplotlib :

  ```
  for (k,i) in enumerate(l):
  data = pd.read_csv(i)
  plt.figure(str(k))
  plt.xlabel("x"+str(k))
  plt.ylabel("y"+str(k))
  plt.plot(data["epoch"],data["f1_score"])
  plt.plot(data["epoch"],data["loss"])
  print(k)
  plt.show()
  ```

  [image]